# shouild i store $_POST variable in another variable or use as it is?

Tags: php

I am using multiple time `$_POST['email']` so my simple question is should I store in another variable like `$a = $_POST['email']` than use `$a` or `$_POST` doesn't affect that much.

Comment: Please go through this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301863/what-are-the-vulnerabilities-in-direct-use-of-get-and-post)

Comment: You should always store it in another variable. It's best to make $email = someFiltersMaybe($_POST['email']);. Then every time when you use your variable $email you will be sure that you are using clean, filtered, correct data. It's best for optimization and especially security purposes.

Comment: and refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6334857/3164682

Comment: @g9m29  Thanks , i already using PDO prepare for that

Comment: Filters are not only for SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

yes its as simple as your question $_POST is a way of getting variable then you can store the value in any variable

```
$a= $_POST['email'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Saving it to a variable would make your code more legible, and increase optimization.

Accessing the POST variable gives no advantages, apart from a slightly smaller source file and slightly less memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

There's very little difference between using a variable and using elements in `$_POST` directly. Performance is about the same and you can make arguments in either direction from a readability perspective.

By the way, be careful with data from the user. Don't assume this has a valid email address in it.